# Tinder like swipe with two button in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

like swipe but with two-button left and right

I am using the package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tindercard

I want not to drag option I want the button to swipe left or right is there any possibility so please help me out. Since the specific dragging mechanism (and math behind it) is what makes this cards move so uniquely and are managed by this guys repo, I guess it's not possible for me to manually manipulate the cards frame to the side on click of a button (at least not in the same way it's done with an actual physical swipe).

My code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tindercard/flutter_tindercard.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class SwipeCard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SwipeCardState createState() => _SwipeCardState();
}

class _SwipeCardState extends State<SwipeCard> {
  List<String> numText = [
    "1 of 1",
    "1 of 2",
    "1 of 3",
    "1 of 4",
    "1 of 5",
    "1 of 6"
  ];
  List<String> cardText = [
    "My First Card",
    "My Second Card",
    "My Third Card",
    "My fourth Card",
    "My fifth Card",
    "My Sixth Card"
  ];
  CardController controller;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          color: Color(0xff2dedaa),
          child: ListView(children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Navigator.push(
                        //     context,
                        //     MaterialPageRoute(
                        //         builder: (context) => PageViewScreen(indexValue: 3,)));
                      },
                      iconSize: 30,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 120,
                    ),
                    Container(
                        height: 40,
                        width: 50,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage(
                            "assets/paw.png",
                          ),
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ))),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 100,
                    ),
                    FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          //   Navigator.push(
                          //       context,
                          //       MaterialPageRoute(
                          //           builder: (context) => PetName()));
                        },
                        child: Text('Skip',
                            style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                Center(
                    child: Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6,
                        child: new TinderSwapCard(
                            orientation: AmassOrientation.TOP,
                            totalNum: 6,
                            stackNum: 3,
                            swipeEdge: 4.0,
                            maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                            maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                            minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                            minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                            cardBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                                  elevation: 2,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                                  ),
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 20,
                                      ),
                                      Text('${numText[index]}'),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 20,
                                      ),
                                      Text('${cardText[index]}'),
                                      Row(children: [
                                          FlatButton(child: Text('yes'),onPressed: (){

                                          },),
                                          FlatButton(child: Text('No'),onPressed: (){

                                          },),

                                      ],)
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                            cardController: controller = CardController(),
                            swipeUpdateCallback:
                                (DragUpdateDetails details, Alignment align) {
                              /// Get swiping card's alignment
                              if (align.x < 0) {
                                
                              } else if (align.x > 0) {
                                //Card is RIGHT swiping
                              }
                            },
                            swipeCompleteCallback:
                                (CardSwipeOrientation orientation, int index) {
                              /// Get orientation & index of swiped card!
                            }))),
              ],
            )
          ])),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Use CardController to trigger swap from outside. Init a CardController as param for widget, and invoke method triggerLeft/Right of your CardController to trigger swipe!

Comment: hi, thanks for response but can you please give me the example of how to use the card controller ??

Comment: Thanks for help I find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Use this logic to solve this issue

```dart
cardText.removeAt(0);
```

cardText is a List

```dart
TinderSwapCard(
                            orientation: AmassOrientation.TOP,
                            totalNum: cardText.length,
)
```